# how to implement javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm looking into javascript inheritance for the first time, and I don't seem to be able to get it to work, or perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly.
So I have some code here, let's have a look at it:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">               
            //object and prototype
            function cat(name){//object constructor
                this.name = name;//property
                this.talk = function(){//method
                    console.log(this.name + " say meeow");
                }
            }           
            cat1 = new cat("Cat 1 Felix")
            cat1.talk();            
            cat2 = new cat("cat 2 Joy")
            cat2.talk()
            //inheritance
            function isleManCat(name){
                cat.call(this,name)
                this.feature = "no tail"
                this.detail = function(){
                    console.log(this.name + " has " + this.feature);
                }
            }
            isleManCat.prototype = new cat();
            cat3 = new isleManCat("isle of Man cat")
            cat3.talk();
            cat3.detail();          
        </script>
```

So I have 2 cats objects here and cat1 and cat2 prints the expected results:

```
Cat 1 Felix say meeow
cat 2 Joy say meeow
```

. Then cat3 is a isleOfMan() cat which should inherit from cat(), and I would have thought that it would inherit the name property from cat() but it prints undefined:

```
undefined say meeow
undefined has no tail
```

Can somebody kindly let me know why it doesn't work and what i'm doing wrong please as I don't seem to understand that?
Thanks

Comment: What name do you expect the cat to have?

Comment: You never specified a name for your `isleManCat` to begin with.

Comment: `isleManCat()` needs to call the constructor it inherited from.  There are thousands of tutorials on inheritance in Javascript and hundreds of answers here on the same topic.  Please read and then ask a much more specific question when you get stuck.  We aren't a generic tutorial service when you haven't done any of your own research.  For example, start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: Are you sure your output still matches your (modified - and please don't do this) code?

Answer (score 1):

Your third kitten deriving `cat` won't produce your expected result because the `cat` constructor won't be called by `isleManCat`'s constructor auto-magically! And your third kitten has no name at all!

```
        // You need to pass the name of the whole cat to this constructor
        // to later give it as argument to base constructor (i.e. cat())
        function isleManCat(name){
            // This is calling cat constructor function setting the "this"
            // keyword to the "this" of isleManCat
            cat.call(this, name);

            this.feature = "no tail"
            this.detail = function(){
                console.log(this.name + " has " + this.feature);
            }
        }
```

In ECMA-Script 5.x you can also use `Function.prototype.apply` and `arguments` reserved keyword to pass `isleOfMan` constructor's arguments as an array to `cat`:

```
        function isleManCat(){
            cat.apply(this, arguments);

            this.feature = "no tail"
            this.detail = function(){
                console.log(this.name + " has " + this.feature);
            }
        }
```

And, in ECMA-Script 2015 and above, you can use *rest parameters*:

```
        function isleManCat(...args){
            // This is calling cat constructor function setting the "this"
            // keyword to the "this" of isleManCat
            cat.apply(this, args);

            this.feature = "no tail"
            this.detail = function(){
                console.log(this.name + " has " + this.feature);
            }
        }
```